# Make a plot in r with a forloop

Tags: r, plot

I am a beginner with coding and I have a dataframe in r. I want to make two barplots in a forloop with r. The x has to be the same column and the y varies over the defined columns. However, everytime I try this only the last plot I create works and the other plot do not work.

I use this code:

```
plot <- names(Cluster6_sum %>% select(`Aantal bedrijven`, Warmtevraag_TJ))

     for (p in plot){
       Cluster6_plot <- ggplot(Cluster6_sum, aes(fill=Industrie, y=get(paste(p)), x=Industrie)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    labs(title = "Totale warmtevraag cluster 6 industrie per sector") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6)) +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5, 'cm'))  +
    geom_text(aes(label=round(`Warmtevraag_TJ`)), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25, size = 2.5) 
    assign(paste("plot",p, sep = "_"), Cluster6_plot)
     }
```

So in this case only the plot of "warmtevraag_TJ" has a good result. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, user23391120! This is a common and frustrating problem, and is a duplicate of several other questions on SO. The norm on SO is to allow those answers (ideally cultivated and full) to be "upvoted" and percolate to the top of searches instead of providing new answers when the question reappears. Please check out the dupe-links. If you go through them and cannot figure out how to resolve your code here, please @-ping me (`@r2evans`) and we can work through the differences. Good luck, and welcome again!

Comment: Bottom line, if you do something like `allplots <- lapply(setNames(nm=c("Aantal bedrijven", "Warmtevraag_TJ")), function(p) { ggplot()...; })` without the `assign`, you should then be able to look at each of `allplots[[1]]`, `allplots[[2]]`, and/or `allplots$Warmtevraag_TJ` to look at individual plots.